# How to scale an application with 50000 Simultaneous Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working on a project which needs to be able to run (for example) 50,000 tasks simultaneously. Each task will run at some frequency (say 5 minutes) and will be either a url ping or an HTTP GET request. My initial plan was to create thread for each task. I ran a basic test to see if this was possible given available system resources. I ran the following code as a console app:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Test1()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000000);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test1));
            t.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, though it started very fast, at the 2000 thread mark, the performance was greatly decreased. By 5000, I could count faster than the program could create threads. This makes getting to 50000 seem like it wouldn't be exactly possible. Am I on the right track or should I try something else? Thanks

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1000000)` just why?

Comment: You should try `Task`... and `Akka.Net` if you want to scale beyond one machine.

Comment: I used thread.sleep(1000000) so that the threads would not close. I wanted to make sure I had all of them running at once

Comment: I'd consider creating a dispatcher that manages invoking each task. You'd have to keep the list of tasks in next-execution order which can be implemented efficiently using a priority queue.

Comment: the .NET Framework has awesome thread pooling capabilities. Look in to `Task`/`async/await`, or other TPL stuff like `Parallel.ForEach()`

Comment: You could potentially do something like this with async/await and reuse threads.  It doesn't make sense to create a thread for each task if your threads are just waiting.  For this test you'd just use Task.Delay() instead of Thread.Sleep()

Comment: Every time you create a thread you are allocating over 1MB for its stack. If you are creating 50,000 threads then you are expecting your PC to have more than 48GB of RAM. No wonder your code is grinding to a halt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many people have the idea that you need to spawn **n** threads if you want to handle **n** tasks in parallel. Most of the time a computer is waiting, it is waiting on I/O such as network traffic, disk access, memory transfer for GPU compute, hardware device to complete an operation, etc.

Given this insight, we can see that a viable solution to handling as many tasks in parallel as possible for a given hardware platform is to pipeline work: place work in a queue and process it using as many threads as possible. Usually, this means 1-2 threads per virtual processor.

In C# we can accomplish this with the Task Parallel Library (TPL):

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static Task RunAsync(int x)
        {
            return Task.Delay(10000);
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 50000).Select(x => RunAsync());

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for tasks to complete...");

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }
```

This queues 50000 work items, and waits until all 50000 tasks are complete. These tasks only execute on as many threads that are needed. Behind the scenes, a task scheduler examines the pool of work and has threads **steal work** from the queue when they need a task to execute.

### Additional Considerations

With a large upper bound (n=50000) you should be cognizant of memory pressure, garbage collector activity, and other task-related overhead. You should consider the following:

- Consider using **ValueTask<T>** to minimize allocations, especially for synchronous operations
- Use **ConfigureAwait(false)** where possible to reduce context switching
- Use **CancellationTokenSource** and **CancellationToken** to cancel requests early (e.g. timeout)
- Follow best practices

  - Avoid awaiting inside of a loop where possible
  - Avoid querying tasks too frequently for completion
  - Avoid accessing **Task<T>.Result** before a task is complete to prevent blocking
  - Avoid deadlocks by using synchronization primitives (mutex, semaphore, condition signal, synclock, etc) as appropriate
  - Avoid frequent use of **Task.Run** to create tasks to avoid exhausting the thread pool available to the default task scheduler (this method is usually reserved for compute-bound tasks)

Comment: Just to add to this for anyone who may have this question. If you want to have tasks which create lists of tasks (i.e. parent and child tasks) add tasks to a list using Task.Factory.StartNew(Action, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent) to make sure the parent task doesn't end before the child task has completed